# Как использовать переменные из цикла? C#

Tags: c#

Например, я создал переменные a1,a2,a3...a100. Как заполнить их по циклу, но не массивом?

---

Дело в том , что я работаю в Windows Forms, мне нужно заполнить массив из 100 разных мест

Comment: Я думаю, это будет долго и неудобно, к тому же я не вижу в этом смысла.

Comment: Не стоит делать из C# PHP. На C# есть более удобные выразительные средства.

Comment: Если вам не лень писать `int a1,a2,a3,a4...` то чем вам не нравится запись `int a1=1,a2=2,a3=3,...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. В winforms можно использовать массивы контролов, только придётся создавать их кодом, а не в дизайнере.
2. Контролы являются ссылочным типом, поэтому можно существующие контролы поместить в массив, если с ними потом надо работать как с массивом (естественно, не для присваивания самих переменных).

Comment: там же в любом контейнере есть список вложенных контролов

Comment: @Grundy, и? Не понимаю, ни как это связано с моим ответом, ни как это связано с вопорсом.

Comment: Ты говоришь про массив контролов, который надо создавать самому, а я говорю, что коллекция этих контролов и так есть

Comment: @Grundy, маловероятно, что тебе надо работать со всеми контролами формы как с массивом. Скорее понадобятся какие-то текстовые поля или что-то в этом духе.

Comment: Ну так если они в одном контейнере лежат - вот тебе и нужная коллекция

Comment: Т. е. у меня есть 100 текстбоксов, а 100 лейблов к ним лежат в соседнем контейнере? Маловероятно же?

Comment: Не понял как сюда этот пример применяется

Answer (score 2):

На самом деле так делать не нужно, для этого используются массивы.

Но если очень хочется то можно, вам необходимо использовать `Reflection`, но необходимо что бы эти переменные были не локально в функции определены, а являлись переменными класса.

Почитать про `Reflection` можно тут - https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/14.1.php

Answer (score 1):

> я создал **переменные** a1,a2,a3...a100. Как заполнить их по циклу, но не
>   массивом?
>   ...мне нужно заполнить **массив**...

СОЗДАЙ МАССИВ, ПЕРЕБЕРИ ЕГО *МЕСТА* *ПО ЦИКЛУ*, ЗАПОЛНЯЯ КАЖДОЕ *МЕСТО*
=)